# Python HTTP Requests with Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, http, ubuntu, python-requests

I am currently achieving, on average, a rate of `250 requests per second` on my Ubuntu machine running Python, using the `requests` library.

I am using 1000 threads. Each thread is configured to, at random, make either a `GET` or a `POST` request to a server. All requests are coming back with data and a `Response 200`.

How do I speed up my number of requests? What is limiting their speed? The system has great hardware: either 16GB or 24GB of memory and what I believe is a quad-core CPU. Currently, each thread is configured to send one request per second, as I have a `time.sleep(1)` in a `while(True)` loop which all of the threads are running, yet, as stated above, I am peaking at 250 requests per second. I have tried setting the delay to `time.sleep(0.1)` or even `time.sleep(0.01)`, but the result is the same: a maximum rate of 250 requests per second.

Comment: Where are these requests going? Same machine? Another machine in the same network? Or some server on the internet?

Comment: They are going to a machine on another network, also operated by me.

Comment: Also, how are you measuring the request rate? Do you count how many requests has been created (before they are complete)? Or Do you count them when the response is received?

Comment: I am counting the number of total requests both by logging them on the receiving end and on the sending end, which validates that number; I am getting the rate by dividing that number by the total seconds elapsed since the first request was made.